What is the uniform worn in this photo from the late 1800s?

I'm researching some family history and I have this photo of my great great grandfather.  As far as I can tell the photo is taken after 1887 (Hellis and Son were so named in 1887) and he died young in 1905.
To the best of my knowledge the family were based in and around South London at the time, and Hellis and Son certainly operated out of London.
Not sure that it's military though.
Any help would be appreciated.

Do you have a better quality scan to make out the details on the shoulder pads and belt buckle

I'm having trouble identifying the uniform as a whole, but the pieces are simple enough.
The hat is a slouch hat broadly identified with colonial British troops.
The distinctive shoulder pads resemble those of light infantry buglers from the Napoleonic period onwards to the present day.
The belt is a snake buckle commonly associated with the later 19th century.
Overall this creates the impression of a British light infantry bugler set for deployment in the Dominions (Australia, New Zealand, South Africa, or possibly Canada)
